# Sending HTML formatted email in Android

Tags: java, android, html, email

I have successfully created an Android app that calculates prices and then is able to transfer that data in a preformatted fashion to an email program of the users choice. Depending upon the data the user creates in the app, a string containing the HTML is read into an intent. The code I have for this is:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailText));
QuoteDroid.this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

This is all fine and the email is ***mostly*** formated correct when I choose the Gmail app, and generally sends ***mostly*** correct. The issue I have with this is that I must send it from a non-gmail account for business purposes. When I choose the generic email app on the phone it does not process the HTML properly and when I send the email it is formated in plain text.

I've read through countless articles and forum posts, but to no avail. How do I process the string, containing the HTML, in such a way that the email -after being sent with the built in email app- is viewed properly formated by the receiver?

Comment: You didn't happen to find any way around this did you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only way around would be to code in the ability to send email from the app, or build a whole new email application for this use. There MIGHT be an app on the Marketplace that sends HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to the individual mail app to properly handle the String that it receives as the EXTRA_TEXT.  A well-behaved mail app will see the mimetype and handle the EXTRA_TEXT appropriately, but not all mail apps do.

Comment: Right, any recommendation on how I should proceed?

Comment: You build the ability to send the email directly from the app: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android