# Android's Email and GMail apps remove HTML formatting from emails

Tags: android, html, email

I have done some searches and I don't think there is anything that answers my question for GMail version 4.6

My problem is that I am unable to render HTML formatting within emails sent from an android app I have created. I am using intents with a text/html type defined. I believe the problem is caused by the GMail application because it strips the HTML from my email before sending.

I have added the code that may be causing the issue unless it is GMail.

```
String body =
       "<table border='1'>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Paint Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (subtotal - ((subtotal * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Paint Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" + String.format("%.2f", subtotal) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Undercoat Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (undercoat - ((undercoat * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Undercoat Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", undercoat) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (total - ((total * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", total) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total VAT</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", ((total *20)/100)) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
       "</table>";

emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Paint Cost");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body)
);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

```
String body =
       "<table border='1'>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Paint Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (subtotal - ((subtotal * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Paint Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" + String.format("%.2f", subtotal) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Undercoat Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (undercoat - ((undercoat * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Undercoat Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", undercoat) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total Cost(Exc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", (total - ((total * 20)/100))) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total Cost(Inc VAT)</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", total) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
                     "<td>Total VAT</td>" +
                     "<td>£" +  String.format("%.2f", ((total *20)/100)) + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
       "</table>";

emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Paint Cost");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Html.fromHtml(body)
);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

However this seems to crash the GMail app instead.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` instead of `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`

Comment: @jumpingcode That just seems to want to crash the Gmail app and it doesn't take the string for the regular Mail app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566641/sending-html-formated-email-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @jumpingcode Is there a way to do this without creating a whole email interface into my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail clients, when invoked via `ACTION_SEND`, allow the user to edit the message, and not all mail clients offer editing of all possible HTML tags. In particular, those that use `EditText` as the foundation for their editors are unlikely to support HTML tablets.

Comment: That makes sense. I just don't understand why it wouldn't support it, it's a bit odd considering Gmail is mostly web based anyway.